# Format to hh:mm input on blur javascript

Tags: javascript, input, time

I have an input that saves time in `hh:mm`, it works actually but only when I put `hh:mm` correctly because, in the backend I take this value and apply a substring to validate `hh` and `mm`, so when I put `07:00` works correctly, but when I put `7:00` it cause an exception because the substring returns a **"7:"**, so i want to `autoformat` this value when the method `onblur` was called, so when I put `7:00` this method will `autoformat` to `07:00`..

**Example:**

> 7:00 -> 07:00
>
> 6:5  -> 06:50

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you using on the backend? Have you tried splitting on ":" and using the resulting array?

Comment: It appears you've forgotten to include a [mcve] showing what you're struggling with. Stack Overflow isn't a free programming service to write your code for you. Please show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: why 6:5 --> 06:50 and not 06:05?

Comment: in the backend is vb, and i tried to validate with substring, but i think that is a good idea splittin on ":", thanks, also i will try to do this on javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
function autoformat(time){
var parts = time.split(':');
return (parts[0].length == 2 ? parts[0] : '0' + parts[0])
    + ':' + (parts[1].length == 2 ? parts[1] : '0' + parts[1]);
}

autoformat('7:00'); // 07:00
```

I really don't get the second example.....
Hope this can help

Comment: forget the second example, i was wrong haha, thanks, i will try :)